# What is the recommended DNS zone name for Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, terraform-provider-azure

I have referred this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns to find the recommended name, but couldn't find one for Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0):

Logic App with Consumption Plan doesn't have private endpoint available. Where as Standard plan of Logic App is same as a web app as it leverages App Service Plan and has networking configuration available , so the same DNS as App Service can be used i.e.

```
Azure Web Apps (Microsoft.Web/sites) / sites    privatelink.azurewebsites.net   azurewebsites.net
```